# Neo4j: Check if node exists and use the result as a condition

Tags: neo4j

Sorry, to ask this question for the 100th time, but none of the previous posts was similar to my problem: I just want to get back TRUE or FALSE if a node with a certain label and a certain property exists.

(u:User {user_id: 1} => TRUE / FALSE

All other posts where about MERGE and so on, but I don't want to create anything, I want to use it as a condition in an apoc.do.when-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Match the node and then check the count of matching nodes if it's greater than zero it means the node exists. Here `node_exists` returns `true/false` you can replace `RETURN` with your apoc statements.

```
MATCH (u:User {user_id: 1})
WITH COUNT(u) > 0  as node_exists
RETURN node_exists
```

Comment: Why not just `MATCH (u:User {user_id: 1}) RETURN COUNT(u) > 0  as node_exists`? There is no need for WITH afaik.

Comment: Because they want to use the `node_exists` value in the next part of the query

Comment: How so? All I read is `I just want to get back TRUE or FALSE if a node with a certain label and a certain property exists.` Our queries are equivalent, except my version removed an unneeded WITH.

Comment: I think you didn’t read the whole question. It’s at the end of the question: `I want to use it as a condition in an apoc.do.when-function.`

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit indeed. What about rewriting the query in a more explicit such as:
`MATCH (u:User {user_id: 1})
WITH COUNT(u) > 0  as node_exists
CALL apoc.do.when(node_exists, [...])`
?